# Generic List<T> property in ViewModel

Tags: c#, generics, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I'm looking to include a generic List property in my ViewModel to enable me to fill that with any kind of IEnumerable list.

It's essentially to create a very simple reporting structure which then uses custom display templates to render a tabular form of the object

Is that possible?

```
public class ReportingViewModel
{
    public List<T> Data { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Then using a model in my custom display template

```
@model List<object>
```

Or similar. I've tried it using `List<T>` or `List<object>` in both the VM and custom template but to no avail.

Comment: The type argument would need to be at the class level

Answer (score 2):

The type argument would need to be at the class level

```
public class ReportingViewModel<T> {
    public List<T> Data { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

and accessed in the view

```
@model ReportingViewModel<MyObject>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Does this mean I would still require a custom template for each object type?

I'm trying to avoid that and having a single Table.cshtml template which takes any object?